# Term for the kind of tools that haven't significantly changed over history

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

I’m looking for a term for the kind of tools
that haven’t significantly changed over history. 
These kind of items first uses usually date from humanity's early days, haven't changed much in form or function across the times and are still widely used.

It may be used in this way:

> Needles are an example of a _______ tool.

Note: If I recall correctly, the age of the item isn't the point, and the unchanging characteristic (or little change across large periods) of the objects is far more important in the definition of this word.

Like spoons that have preserved its basic shape and function for milennia even if they are ergonomic now and the materials they are built with aren't the rocks in your yard any more.

I heard the word in a history class something like 12 years ago,
so my definition may be a bit off.

Comment: an example of a *traditional* tool.

Comment: When I did an evening class in Plumbing, we used wooden tools to shape the lead used on rooftop lead flashings. The tools have not changed in two thousand years since the Romans used them. I would call them _traditional_ tools.

Comment: @NigelJ that's a great example Nigel, although "traditional tool" doesn't ring a bell. My guess is that the word I'm looking for may be some kind of anthropological term that isn't widely known outside that area.

Comment: (1) People generally use [tag:single-word-requests] questions to find the best word to fit a definition, or to fit in a context.  If you’re trying to remember a specific word that you heard over a decade ago but have forgotten, you should probably make that clearer, and do your best to narrow down the context and meaning of the original word.  (2) I wrote my answer before your edit; now I don’t know whether it’s even close to what you want.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  At the very least, please clarify: are you talking about things that ‘‘usually date from humanity’s early days’’, or are you looking for a word that can (non-jokingly) be used to refer to email?  Your statement: ‘‘the unchanging characteristic of the objects is far more important in the definition of this word’’ doesn’t really help; email has evolved since its invention. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (In the early days of big, isolated computing centers, email could be used only between local users. I.e., email predated ubiquitous networking. And, initially, email was plain text only. The ability to send HTML or other “rich text” (i.e., using fonts, font faces (bold, italic and underline), color, and non-ASCII characters) and multi-media (images, audio and video) is also a “recent” development.)

Comment: possibly ur-tool.   ur means original, primitive.  But this doesn't really fit with what you are asking, because you need to say more to convey that the shape and function has not changed much over thousands of years, i.e., "there isn't much difference between the ur-spoon and Tiffany's latest design."   Love this Q, and I hope you get a good answer.

Comment: @Scott Thanks, I've upvoted your answer because I found it perfectly acceptable and "Primitive" is a very usable replacement. Email has changed but not massively. In the same line, needles have changed, now we have curve needles, hollow needles for syringes, and what not. But I recall that needles and spoons were examples given by the professor at that time. For what I can remember, age wasn't the point. The perfection of its design and how well it fitted its task was the point. I searched for tags before posting but if you can recommend a few that better fit my question I'll appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to use ***primitive***:

> [American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=primitive):
>
> - Of or relating to an early or original stage or state; primeval: 
>     *life in the primitive ocean.*
>
>   Occurring in or characteristic of
>     an early stage of development or evolution: 
>     *fossils of primitive angiosperms from the Cretaceous Period.*
>
>   Having developed early in the evolutionary history of a group: 
>     *Hair is a primitive trait of mammals.*
>
>   Regarded as having changed little in evolutionary history.
>     Not in scientific use: 
>     *The coelacanth is a primitive fish.*
>
> [Macmillan Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/primitive_1):
>
>   very simple in design -
>   *primitive tools*
>   -
>   *a primitive camera*
>   - old-fashioned, simple, and without modern features or comforts
>       *The conditions in the camp were fairly primitive.*
>       *a remote and primitive cottage in the mountains*
>
> [Collins English Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/primitive):
>
>   If you describe something as
>   **primitive**
>   ,
>     you mean that it is very simple in style or very old-fashioned.
>
> [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/primitive):
>
>   Relating to, denoting, or preserving the character
>     of an early stage in the evolutionary or historical development of something.
>   *‘primitive mammals’*
>   *‘a name corrupted from primitive German’*
>   - Relating to or denoting a preliterate, nonindustrial society or culture
>       characterized by simple social and economic organization.
>       *‘primitive people’*

but you have to be careful to make your meaning clear,
as *primitive* has multiple definitions. 
It can also mean *ancient*. 
In addition to the above definitions, note:

> [Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/primitive_1):
>
>   at a very simple stage of development, before modern technology
>   *a primitive society/tribe*
>   - relating to a very early stage
>       in the development of humans, animals, or plants
>       *primitive man/life*
>       *primitive creatures like jellyfish and corals*
>
> [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/primitive):
>
> - **Primitive** means belonging to a society
>     in which people live in a very simple way,
>     usually without industries or a writing system.
>     *...studies of primitive societies.*
>     *...primitive tribes.*
>
>   **Primitive** means belonging to a very early period
>     in the development of an animal or plant.
>     *...primitive whales.*
>     *Primitive humans needed to be able to react like this
>     to escape from dangerous animals.*
>     *It is a primitive instinct to flee a place of danger.*

so, if you are not clearly referring to something that is in current use,
readers might assume that you are referring to an antiquated, historic artifact.

*Primitive* can also mean *crude* and *unsophisticated:*

> [AHD](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=primitive):
>
> - Characterized by simplicity or crudity; unsophisticated: 
>     *primitive weapons.*
>
>   Of or relating to a nonindustrial, often tribal culture,
>     especially one that is characterized by an absence of literacy
>     and a low level of economic or technological complexity: 
>     *primitive societies.*

so you should indicate that you are talking about something that hasn’t evolved
because it didn’t need to; the early design is adequate for current usage.

---

On the same page in the dictionary: consider also ***primordial***:

> [American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=primordial):
>
> - Being or happening first in sequence of time; original.
>
>   Primary or fundamental:
>     *play a primordial role.*

but it is generally defined to mean old in a cosmological sense:

> [Macmillan Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/primordial):
>
>   formed when the Earth or universe began
>
> [Collins English Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/primordial):
>
>   You use
>   **primordial**
>   to describe things
>     that belong to a very early time in the history of the world.
>   [formal]
>   *Twenty million years ago, Idaho was populated by dense primordial forest.*
>   *...the original primordial explosion.*
>
> [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/primordial):
>
>   Existing at or from the beginning of time; primeval.
>   *‘the primordial oceans’*

Answer (score 1):

Because you think you may be looking for an anthropological term, I suggest ***ur-***

According to the [Oxford English Dictionary](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/220312?rskey=7RXE8j&result=2#eid)

> ur, prefix, denoting ‘primitive, original, earliest,’ as ur-Hamlet,
>   ur-origin, ur-stock
>
> Example: 1926   A. Møller tr. J. Pedersen Israel I. i. 245   The word
>   shēm is found in all Semitic languages and belongs to the absolutely
>   certain ur-semitic components

Because OED is behind a pay-wall, here is another source, [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/ur-#etymonline_v_4555):

> prefix meaning "original, earliest, primitive," from German ur- "out
>   of, original," from Proto-Germanic *uz- "out," from PIE *ud- "up, out"
>   (see out (adv.)) At first only in words borrowed from German (such as
>   ursprache "hypothetical primitive language"); since mid-20c. a living
>   prefix in English.

This may not be exactly what you are looking for, because ur- by itself doesn't necessarily mean that the ur-object hasn't changed its form over the millennia, but it carries a strong implication that it hasn't.  For example (made up):

> A Cro-Magnon would have no trouble using the latest sterling silver
>   spoon made by Tiffany, because although shinier, it is essentially the
>   ur-spoon she had been using all her life.

Answer (score 0):

I would use *age-old* in that sentence.

Other possibilities include

*ancient*       'having had an existence of many years' as in *ancient customs*
 *primal*         'original, primitive', as in *village life continued in its primal innocence*
 
*primeval*     'of or relating to the earliest ages (as of the world or human history)', as in
 
                              *100 acres of primeval forest which has never felt an ax* 
 
*primordial* 'existing in or persisting from the beginning (as of a solar system or universe)", as in
 
                              *a primordial gas cloud*
*venerable*   'impressive by reason of age'

All definitions from [*Merriam-Webster*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/).

Comment: Thanks, I've edited the question to clarify that age is a tangential characteristic of the items and not strictly necessary for them to belong to the category named with this word.

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible that the form of the tool hasn't changed for a long time because the tool has been developed to the optimum design for the given task and materials.  For example, a well-designed knife for hand-cleaning fish will work well without change for millennia.

So, **fully-evolved** or **optimized** seem to satisfy the question.